# sbt 1.3.8 displaying a lot of useless messages

Tags: sbt

After I upgrade sbt to 1.3.8, I see a lot of unuseful messages in the sbt console, which is very annoying. I searched online but didn't find a good key word. Does anyone know how to disable the messages showing like below?

```
  | => Zero / checkBuildSources / dynamicInputs 0s


  | => Zero / checkBuildSources / dynamicInputs 0s





  | => Global / previousCache 0s

  | => Zero / checkBuildSources / dynamicInputs 0s



  | => Global / previousCache 0s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These messages are progress logging from the sbt "super-shell". You can disable it using the `sbt.supershell` option, e.g.

```
sbt -Dsbt.supershell=false
```

Or by adding it to your `.sbtopts` file or `SBT_OPTS` env var (check `sbt -help` for details on how to use them). See also [Command Line Options](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Command+Line+Options) for the reference.