# Globally disable sbt supershell

Tags: scala, command-line, configuration, sbt

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432711/sbt-1-3-8-displaying-a-lot-of-useless-messages) I'd like to stop sbt from spamming the shell with messages and blank lines. It stops if I run sbt with the option `sbt -Dsbt.supershell=false`, but I'd like to disable it globally via a dotfile in `~/.sbt` or similar. I could replace the `sbt` binary with a wrapper which always adds this option, but that seems inelegant.

I've tried each of the following in a file called `~/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt` and `~/.sbt/1.3/global.sbt`, but none have an effect:

```
sbt.supershell := false
useSuperShell := false
sbt.useSuperShell := false
useSuperShell := false
supershell := false
ThisBuild / useSuperShell := false
```

As an example of what I'm trying to avoid, here's what happens when I start `sbt` for a project I'm working on (a similar amount of spam gets sprinkled around when compiling, testing, etc.):

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from metals.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/chris/.sbt/1.0/plugins















  | => global-plugins / updateCacheName 0s





  | => global-plugins / updateCacheName 0s
  | => Global / skip 0s





  | => global-plugins / updateCacheName 0s
  | => Global / skip 0s






  | => global-plugins / updateCacheName 0s






  | => global-plugins / updateCacheName 0s


















































































  | => global-plugins / update 0s
  | => global-plugins / Runtime / unmanagedClasspath 0s





  | => global-plugins / scalaCompilerBridgeResolvers 0s
  | => global-plugins / Compile / externalHooks 0s
  | => global-plugins / Compile / externalHooks 0s
  | => global-plugins / dependencyPositions 0s
  | => global-plugins / update 0s
  | => global-plugins / Runtime / unmanagedClasspath 0s





  | => global-plugins / moduleSettings 0s
  | => global-plugins / csrConfiguration 0s
  | => global-plugins / projectDescriptors 0s
  | => global-plugins / dependencyPositions 0s
  | => global-plugins / update 0s
  | => global-plugins / Runtime / unmanagedClasspath 0s





  | => global-plugins / csrRecursiveResolvers 0s
  | => global-plugins / moduleSettings 0s
  | => global-plugins / csrConfiguration 0s
  | => global-plugins / projectDescriptors 0s
  | => global-plugins / dependencyPositions 0s
  | => global-plugins / update 0s
  | => global-plugins / Runtime / unmanagedClasspath 0s





  | => global-plugins / csrRecursiveResolvers 0s
  | => global-plugins / moduleSettings 0s
  | => global-plugins / csrConfiguration 0s
  | => global-plugins / projectDescriptors 0s
  | => global-plugins / dependencyPositions 0s
  | => global-plugins / update 0s
  | => global-plugins / Runtime / unmanagedClasspath 0s


































  | => global-plugins / update 0s
  | => global-plugins / Runtime / unmanagedClasspath 0s










  | => global-plugins / update 0s
  | => global-plugins / Runtime / unmanagedClasspath 0s










  | => global-plugins / update 0s
  | => global-plugins / Runtime / unmanagedClasspath 0s











  | => global-plugins / update 0s











  | => global-plugins / Compile / previousCompile 0s











  | => global-plugins / Compile / compileIncremental 0s











  | => global-plugins / Compile / compileIncremental 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 0s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 1s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 1s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 1s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 1s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 1s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 1s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 1s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 1s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 1s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 2s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 2s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 2s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 2s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 2s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 2s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 2s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 2s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 2s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 2s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 3s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 3s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 3s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 3s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 3s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 3s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 3s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 3s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 3s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 4s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 4s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 4s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 4s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 4s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 4s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 4s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 4s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 4s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 4s











  | => <anon-3eb292cd> 5s












[info] Loading project definition from /Users/chris/repos/scalacheck-demo/project





  | => scalacheck-demo-build / bootResolvers 0s





  | => scalacheck-demo-build / bootResolvers 0s





  | => scalacheck-demo-build / bootResolvers 0s

















  | => scalacheck-demo-build / bootResolvers 0s





  | => scalacheck-demo-build / otherResolvers 0s





  | => scalacheck-demo-build / dependencyPositions 0s





  | => scalacheck-demo-build / dependencyPositions 0s











  | => Global / classpathEntryDefinesClass 0s





  | => scalacheck-demo-build / Compile / discoveredSbtPlugins 0s





  | => scalacheck-demo-build / csrFallbackDependencies 0s
  | => scalacheck-demo-build / Compile / unmanagedSources / allInputPathsAndAttributes 0s
  | => scalacheck-demo-build / Compile / externalHooks 0s







  | => scalacheck-demo-build / Compile / compileIncremental 0s








[info] Loading settings for project scalacheck-demo from secrets.sbt,build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to scalacheckdemo (in build file:/Users/chris/repos/scalacheck-demo/)















  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





  | => Global / previousCache 0s





  | => Global / checkBuildSources 0s





















  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





  | => Zero / checkBuildSources / dynamicInputs 0s
  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





  | => Global / previousCache 0s
  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s






















  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





















  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





  | => Global / previousCache 0s
  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s






















  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s





  | => Global / previousCache 0s
  | => Global / fileTreeView 0s







[info] sbt server started at local:///Users/chris/.sbt/1.0/server/bba992971696ad25eaa9/sock
sbt:scalacheckdemo>
```

Comment: How about `alias sbt="sbt -Dsbt.supershell=false"` in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[sbt launcher script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package#sbt-the-launcher-script) provides `sbt -help` which should printout the location of global configuration which on my machine after running `brew install sbt` to install sbt 1.3.12 gives

```
  SBT_OPTS            environment variable, if unset uses ""
  .sbtopts            if this file exists in the current directory, its contents
                      are prepended to the runner args
  /usr/local/etc/sbtopts    if this file exists, it is prepended to the runner args
```

So try putting

```
-Dsbt.supershell=false
```

in `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts` which is sbt's system-wide configuration file. However I can see that the default location specified in [source](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/76d3c88ad9c45cfdb3be0f47b0f28ebbcd89fe26/src/universal/bin/sbt#L416) code is `/etc/sbt/sbtopts` which then `brew` seems to [replace](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/e938860532572b9455242ff46345e9d1ed368ca2/Formula/sbt.rb#L14)

```
s.gsub! 'etc_sbt_opts_file="/etc/sbt/sbtopts"', "etc_sbt_opts_file=\"#{etc}/sbtopts\""
```

hence I think the safest bet is to just run `sbt -h` to see what is the value on your machine. I am not familiar with nixpkgs but you could have a look at the its [source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/222196b9d6dcb4335a44995b313654db78388faa/pkgs/development/tools/build-managers/sbt/default.nix) for sbt, or directly analyse `etc_sbt_opts_file` variable in the resulting sbt launcher script with perhaps

```
vim `which sbt`
```

Comment: `SBT_OPTS` and `.sbtopts` in the project directory both work, but `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts` doesn't work for me (on macOS). I also tried `/etc/sbtopts` and `~/.sbtopts` to see if they would work, but unfortunately they don't work either :(

Comment: I've accepted this answer, since putting `.sbtopts` in each project isn't too bad: I can flag it in `.gitignore`, and it won't affect other developers

Comment: @Warbo Did you install with `brew install sbt`?

Comment: No it's installed using Nix (nixpkgs and nix-darwin) https://github.com/Warbo/nix-config/blob/master/overrides/metaPackages.nix#L71