# Configuring SBT global settings

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to permanently turn on the `-verbose` setting for SBT, without having to type it each time. What's the best way to do this? Putting `-verbose` in $SBT_OPTS does not have an effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-verbose` flag can be enabled system-wide by saving it in [global `sbtopts`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231005/5205022) configuration file. For example, on my machine, it is located at

```
/usr/local/etc/sbtopts
```

Here is an example of its contents

```
# set memory options
-mem   2048

# java version (default: java from PATH, currently $(java -version |& grep version))
-java-home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home

-verbose
```

---

Addressing the comment regarding IntelliJ, note that IntelliJ Scala Plugin currently does not read global `sbtopts`, however it does have support for local `.sbtopts` configuration file, but it does [not](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/commit/07f2fb65b31a736ea4cba5673570729727e09f5e) support every option provided by [sbt launcher script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package) proper:

```
Supported options:
    -no-share, -no-global, -sbt-boot, -sbt-dir, -ivy, -jvm-debug,
    all options with -D and -J prefixes

Unsupported options:
    -S prefix seems to be unsupported by sbt-launcher itself
    -mem has a bit untrivial algorithm, same thing can be achieved
        by configuring -Xmx, -Xms, -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize options
    -sbt-version, -sbt-rc, -sbt-snapshot, -sbt-jar
        and -java-home are overriden by IDEA options

Other options have no impact on project importing process
```

[SbtOpts.scala](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/blob/b95ef95e0970de73b15feef4d9fe29ab4371dc67/scala/scala-impl/src/org/jetbrains/sbt/project/structure/SbtOpts.scala) should list all the supported options. One notable absence is support for `-mem`, which means if we put, say, `-mem 4096` in `.sbtopts`, then IntelliJ will simply ignore it. Similarly, the flag `-verbose` will not be picked up by IntelliJ sbt runner.

Hence the key is to understand that sbt runner script proper is not the same as IntelliJ custom made sbt runner component.

Comment: Not working for me, could it be because I'm also setting `$SBT_OPTS` in `.bashrc`? Or do I need something to get it to trigger? Using version 1.3.12

Comment: @ClickUpvote Seems to work on my machine with same sbt version 1.3.12. I do not set `SBT_OPTS` or do anything special beyond putting `-verbose` in `sbtopts`.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc Maybe the global `sbtopts` is not being picked up. Could you try adding to it some nonsense flag such as `--asdf` and then see if sbt errors after starting? This should tell us if at least global config file is read.

Comment: missed the file. it works if read from `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts`

Comment: No, that doesn't work, however I found out about `.sbtopts` through your answer. Putting that file in the project dir does work. Want to put that in your answer? And I'll accept

Comment: Any ideas why when Intellij launches SBT through the launcher.jar, that seems to override the .sbtopts? Here's the command: `/home/ali/.sdkman/candidates/java/14.0.1.j9-adpt/bin/java -server -Dsbt.supershell=false -Xmx50000M -Didea.managed=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /home/ali/.sdkman/candidates/sbt/1.3.13/bin/sbt-launch.jar early(addPluginSbtFile=\"\"\"/tmp/idea1.sbt\"\"\") "; set ideaPort in Global := 37535 ; idea-shell"`

Comment: why delete the part about the `.sbtops` file? the answer you linked also says it only worked when they added it, and same for me

Comment: @ClickUpvote Official [sbt launcher script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/7d75936b0248446297a0559e21e31fcefece7c25/src/universal/bin/sbt#L472) should support global `sbtopts`. Executing `sbt -h` should display the location of the file. If you are using other ways of launching sbt, such as via IntelliJ or other custom launcher scripts then those scripts will likely have their own ways of configuring.

Answer (score 4):

if you use `unix` friendly environment, you can create an alias for `sbt` in your `~/.bash/profile` for example

```sh
alias sbt=sbt -verbose
```

Comment: This is great for terminal but won't extend to intellij which launches sbt using the sbt-launcher jar rather than thru the command